# Why Doesn't CreateProcess() Work?

Tags: winapi, createprocess, compatibility-mode

I have a program that attempts to restart Explorer in Windows 7; it first ends the process, then starts it again.

Simple?

So it looks -- it indeed seems to work. However, I noticed something funny: *When I try to start a program (say, XP's Power Calculator powertoy) under **compatibility mode**, it no longer works!* Nothing happens -- the process is created and immediately quits.

If I run Explorer through the Run dialog of Task Manager, the program runs fine.

What's going on?!

```
#include <windows.h>
int main()
{
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    STARTUPINFO si = {sizeof(si)};
    TCHAR path[] = TEXT("explorer");
    DWORD f = 0; //I tried a variety of these flags; didn't work
    return CreateProcess(NULL, path, NULL, NULL, FALSE, f, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
}
```

#### Edit 1:

- The fact that it was 32-bit with WOW64 redirection disabled made no difference. I made it 64-bit and the issue was the same.
- I tried `ShellExecute` but it didn't work either.

### Edit 2:

**The same exact code** just worked for me a couple of times, and then stopped working again... huh?

Comment: why are you doing this? explorer.exe is not designed to be used in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really an answer to the "why", but I managed to find out *how* to fix it myself:

Instead of copying environmental variables from the current process, if I copy them with [`CreateEnvironmentBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762270%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), then it works.

I still haven't figured out what's causing it, though...